Solr search not preserving spanish terms while searching like válvula converted to v??lvula
For Solr search, I see when I am searching for term válvula on search query, it is converting the term to v??lvula and giving me irrelevant results.
I am not sure why this happens? And any idea on how to preserve the same.
I tried searching manually on Solr and I can confirm this happens on Solr query when I am running it through browser directly.

What type of field are you indexing to? Is it a text in English or a text general?

Is it removing the accent on the á, and converting it into a ordinary 'a'?
If so, this is most likely done in the ASCII Folder Filter:
https://solr.apache.org/guide/6_6/filter-descriptions.html
You can check in the Solr Backend what exactly is happening with the search term, in this example the German umlaut ä is replaced with an 'a':

